# CodeIgniter Check if database is wrong

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I'm working on a small application that connects to a database and retrieves data from tables. But I need to display to the caller that I wasn't able to connect to the specified host. How can I accomplish that? I've tried to use this snippet but it doesnt work:

```
define('ERROR_STR', 'ERROR: ');
# ...
if ($this->db->_error_number() OR $this->db->_error_message()) {
    die(ERROR_STR . $this->db->_error_number() . ': ' . $this->db->_error_message());
}
```

In my logs I get this listed:

```
ERROR - 2015-04-09 15:18:19 --> Severity: Warning  --> mysqli_connect(): (HY000/2005): Unknown MySQL server host 'localhosta' (2)
```

But I need to check in runtime (after trying to connect, obviously) if database config params are wrong (host/user/password)  and echo that error msg back to the caller. $this->db->_error_number() and $this->db->_error_message() are not giving me that error msgs.
Any ideas? Hope I was clear enough. Thanks.

EDIT:

Here's my db config:

```
$db['default']['hostname'] = 'localhost';
$db['default']['username'] = '';
$db['default']['password'] = '';
$db['default']['database'] = '';
$db['default']['dbdriver'] = 'mysql';
$db['default']['dbprefix'] = '';
$db['default']['pconnect'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['db_debug'] = FALSE;
$db['default']['cache_on'] = FALSE;
$db['default']['cachedir'] = '';
$db['default']['char_set'] = 'utf8';
$db['default']['dbcollat'] = 'utf8_general_ci';
$db['default']['swap_pre'] = '';
$db['default']['autoinit'] = FALSE;
$db['default']['stricton'] = FALSE;
```

But it is merged to the real db config array in my controller:

```
    $this->connected = false;

    $this->load->database(array_merge(array(
        'hostname' => "localhost",
        'username' => "username",
        'password' => "password",
        'database' => "database",
        'dbdriver' => "mysqli",
        'dbprefix' => "",
        'pconnect' => FALSE,
        'db_debug' => FALSE,
        'cache_on' => FALSE,
        'cachedir' => "",
        'char_set' => "utf8",
        'dbcollat' => "utf8_general_ci",
                    ), (array) $json->conn), TRUE);

    if ($this->db->initialize() !== FALSE) {
        die('Not CONNECTED!');
    }

    $this->connected = true;
```

But I get a error in my logs for this line

```
if ($this->db->initialize() !== FALSE) {
```

saying

```
ERROR - 2015-04-09 15:47:48 --> Severity: Notice  --> Undefined property: Main::$db /.../.../...
```

I have no idea of whats wrong.

Comment: "Unknown MySQL server host 'localhosta'" is quite a clear message for invalid db connection configuration

Comment: set $db['default']['db_debug'] = FALSE; to show error

Comment: @Cristik, yea, but I want to get that message inside my controller so I can display it to the user. Dunno how or when that's been written to the logs. '-'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Removing the last parameter of `$this->load->database` (which defaults to `FALSE`) really did the rest of the job.

This is the new code from my controller:

```
$this->connected = false;

$this->load->database(array_merge(array(
    'hostname' => "localhost",
    'username' => "root",
    'password' => "root",
    'database' => "automaserv",
    'dbdriver' => "mysqli",
    'dbprefix' => "",
    'pconnect' => FALSE,
    'db_debug' => FALSE,
    'cache_on' => FALSE,
    'cachedir' => "",
    'char_set' => "utf8",
    'dbcollat' => "utf8_general_ci",
), (array) $json->conn));

if ($this->db->initialize() === FALSE) {
    die('Not CONNECTED!');
}

$this->connected = true;
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

you can put you initial connection in to a try catch block

```
try{
   $this->load->database(array_merge(array(
    'hostname' => "localhost",
    'username' => "username",
    'password' => "password",
    'database' => "database",
    'dbdriver' => "mysqli",
    'dbprefix' => "",
    'pconnect' => FALSE,
    'db_debug' => FALSE,
    'cache_on' => FALSE,
    'cachedir' => "",
    'char_set' => "utf8",
    'dbcollat' => "utf8_general_ci",
                ), (array) $json->conn), TRUE);

} catch (exception $e){
    echo "can't connect";

}
```

Comment: nothing as in you still see the error or you don't see the "can't connect"?

Comment: By 'nothing happens' I meant that the issue persists. But now it's fixed, as I mentioned in my answer. Thanks, anyways.